# How can I use epsilon-delta to solve this problem?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

1. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  be continuous and differentiable at every point $x\in\mathbb{R}−\{c\}$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
2. $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=C$.

How can I prove the sentence below? 
$$
\lim_{x→c}\frac{f(x)−f(c)}{x−c}=C
$$
I know that I have to use mean-value theorem and epsilon-delta, but I don't know exactly how can I use the epsilon-delta to prove this problem.

Comment: You don't need $\varepsilon-\delta$.  Use the mean value theorem twice, once to compute the limit as $x\to c^+$ and once to compute the limit as $x\to c^-$

Comment: But I don't think lim_{x→c-}f′(x)=C is same as lim_{x→c-}(f(x)−f(c))/(x−c)=C.(+ is also...) What part should I have to apply that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a sequence $x_n\uparrow c.$  By the mean value theorem, for each $n$ there is a $x_n<d_n<c$ such that $$\frac{f(x_n)−f(c)}{x_n−c}=f'(d_n)$$  As $x_n\uparrow c$, $d_n\to c$ so we have 
$$\lim_{x\uparrow c}\frac{f(x)−f(c)}{x−c}=\lim_{x\uparrow c}f'(x)=C,$$
and similarly for $x_n\downarrow c.$